# Less::ParseError: variable @box-border-radius is undefined while compiling on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, less, assets

Using less-rails and application.less in my rails application. Everything works well on my local and site is working fine. But when I deploy on heroku it gives an error in

```
Less::ParseError: variable @box-border-radius is undefined
```

Although I have imported variables.less on top of application.less file but it stills not working

application.less

```
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap";

// Overrides
@import "admin/modules/bootstrap-override";

// Modules
@import "admin/modules/variables";
@import "admin/modules/material-colors";
@import "admin/modules/mixins";
@import "admin/modules/core";
.....
```

production.rb

```
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.compile = true

config.assets.digest = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'less-rails', '~> 2.7.0'
```

assets.rb

```
  Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
  Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
```

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using, and how are you providing it (gem, npm package, etc)? You should see a similar error if you run locally `rails asset:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`, does it come with a nicer backtrace?

Comment: Yes I see the same error when i run this command on local...no nicer backtrace